# VS2010 - ASP.NET Configuration Won't Open

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a standard ASP.NET project. I have created a login control on the page and now I would like to start adding the option to register as a member on my page.

My problem is that when I click "Asp.net Configuration" in the solution explorer or under the Projects tab. Nothing opens up.

I have made sure that my project is not running, the configuration window just won't open.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SOLVED! I had exactly the same problem, Firefox was my default browser, after I reset Internet Explorer as the default browser, it worked!  The configuration page is (for some silly reason) a web page, and perhaps it only jives with IE.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, but I didn't want to keep switching from Firefox to IE to solve the issue. Digging a bit deeper, it seems the provided URL is incomplete. You need to use the following template:

```
http://localhost:<port>/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=<projectPath>&applicationUrl=/
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Setting IE as default browser is the fastest solution, however if you are not afraid to put 30 seconds more effort, this solution is better, just keep in mind for the <projectPath> to escape spaces e.g. ?applicationPhysicalPath=C:\Documents\Visual%20Studio%202010\Projects\YourSolution\YourProject&applicationUrl=/

Comment: The IE answer did not work for me. This did. Any way to permanently change the link?

Answer (score 3):

First check if you have an aspnetdb.mdf under the App_Data subfolder of that you previously set up the needed tables for the application services in another database.

If you haven't got these then build the solution and navigate to the page which has the login control on it. Normally ASP.NET will generate the needed database `aspnetdb.mdf`in the App_Data folder. Once you have that database you should be able to use the configuration which starts a web application with which you can create your users and define the roles to which they belong.

Grz, Kris.

Comment: Something is opening now, but when the web-browser opens up I am getting an error.

The asp.net web administration tool is giving me this error - "
An error was encountered. Please return to the previous page and try again. "

Comment: And when you try again, then what happens? Another thing to check: is the path to the application longer than 100 characters? I've seen people stating that as a possible error.

Comment: I had this exact same problem.  Apparently the ASP.NET Web Administration Tool does not like paths with "non-standard" characters or even spaces!  My solution was located in a path that contained many spaces (ie. "C:\Source Code\My Source Code\...") simply replacing the spaces with an underscore character ("_") solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, if web.config file is not opening on VS editor, ASP Configuration browser page won't appear, so make sure that web.config is open in the VS editor and then try to access the Configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue with a brand new ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2012.

When trying to open **Project** --> **ASP.NET Configuration** from Visual Studio, it was saying: `An error was encountered. Please return to the previous page and try again.`

The path to my application was: `E:\\_Dev\C#\Site`

I changed the Path to: `E:\\_Dev\Web\Site` and guess what? **It works**.

So even the # from C# was causing an issue. This thing is very picky on special characters...